# Тип аргументов лямбда-функции с++

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Создаю небольшую систему событий, и если с обычными функциями и методами классов всё определено, то появляется проблема с лямбда-функциями, а именно нужно как-то вытащить типы аргументов из лямбды (и вставить вместо ???). Это вообще возможно как-то сделать?

```
template<class... _Args>
class AbstractEventHandler {
public:
    virtual void call(_Args... args) = 0;
    virtual ~AbstractEventHandler() {}
protected:
    AbstractEventHandler() {}
};

template<class _HandleFunction>
class LambdaEventHandler : 
    public AbstractEventHandler<???>
{
private:
    _HandleFunction _handle_function;
public:
    LambdaEventHandler(const _HandleFunction& handle_function) : _handle_function(handle_function) {}
    LambdaEventHandler(_HandleFunction&& handle_function) : _handle_function(handle_function) {}
public:
    virtual void call(???) override {
        _handle_function(???);
    }
};

template<class _HandleFunction>
LambdaEventHandler(_HandleFunction)->LambdaEventHandler<_HandleFunction>;

template <class... _Args>
class Event {
private:
    std::list<AbstractEventHandler<_Args...>*> _handlers;
public:
    Event& operator += (AbstractEventHandler<_Args...>& handler) {
        _handlers.push_back(&handler);
        return *this;
    }
    void operator()(_Args... args) {
        for (auto&& handler : _handlers) {
            handler->call(args...);
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: `template<typename HandleFunction, typename... Args> class LambdaEventHandler : public AbstractEventHandler<Args...>`

Comment: А зачем конструктор `LambdaEventHandler(_HandleFunction&& handle_function)`, который делает то же самое, что и предыдущий?

Comment: И разве идентификаторы типа `_Args` не зарезервированы?

Comment: @dIm0n, всё таки компилятор считает, что константная ссылка только для копирования и не позволяет принимать r-vaue объекты, и _Args не зарезервированны

Comment: @КириллЧуркин первое https://godbolt.org/z/hf55Ko; второе "the identifiers that begin with an underscore followed by an uppercase letter are reserved;" https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/identifiers, раз уж не верите

Answer (score 0):

Собственно мне удалось решить проблему следующим образом

Для начала сделаем пак типов

```
namespace {
    template<class... _Args>
    struct pack {};
}
```

Будем использовать его в немного переделанном классе `LambdaEventHandler`

```
template<class... Unused>
class LambdaEventHandler;

template<class _HandleFunction, class... _Args>
class LambdaEventHandler<_HandleFunction, ::pack<_Args...>> :
    public AbstractEventHandler<_Args...>
{
private:
    _HandleFunction _handle_function;
public:
    LambdaEventHandler(const _HandleFunction& handle_function) : _handle_function(handle_function) {}
    LambdaEventHandler(_HandleFunction&& handle_function) : _handle_function(handle_function) {}
public:
    virtual void call(_Args... args) override {
        _handle_function(args...);
    }
};
```

Далее нужно создать метафункцию, которая вытащит этот пак из `std::function`

```
namespace {
    template<class... _Args>
    struct get_function_args;

    template<class... _Args>
    struct get_function_args<std::function<void(_Args...)>> {
        using args_pack = pack<_Args...>;
    };
}
```

Далее нам нужно только определение функции, которая вернёт нам `std::function`, выглядит глупо, но надо, без неё не вытащить `std::function` с шаблонными параметрами

```
template<class... Args>
auto to_function(std::function<void(Args...)>)->std::function<void(Args...)>;
```

И последнее это модифицированный deduction guide для `LambdaEventHandler`

```
template<class _HandleFunction>
LambdaEventHandler(_HandleFunction handle_function)->LambdaEventHandler < _HandleFunction, typename ::get_function_args<decltype(to_function(std::function(handle_function)))>::args_pack>;
```

Естественно буду рад более красивым и элегантным вариантам

Comment: много слов, но мало смысла _ лично я так оцениваю и ваш вопрос и ваш ответ